# NameError: uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I'm using Rails 3.2.3 and Carrierwave 1.8.21

trying to install Carrierwave_backgrounder according to the instructions in https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder result in

```
NameError: uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay
```

because of the following line which is added to the uploader

```
include ::CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay
```

I tried without including this line and the result is duplicate processing of the images (both delayed and not delayed)

how do I fix that ?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you may need to bundle and restart your rails server.

```
➜  ~  bundle install
```